# Updating var in function with slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, but all that happens when I move my slider is that the functions will restart. I want the function to update with the value of the slider position.

Edit: here is the entire page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,       minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
    <title>sliding</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"   />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>

    <script src="assets/js/simple-slider.js"></script>

    <link href="assets/css/simple-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/simple-slider-volume.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <script src="assets/js/timbre.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="app container">

        <!-- start building -->
    <script> 

    var x=200; 
    function sin(){T("sin", {freq:x, mul:0.5}).play();}

    $('#slider').on('change', function(){
    x = $(this).val();
    });


    </script> 

    <button onclick="sin()"></button>

    <input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1,000" id="slider">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the [jQuery Simple Slider](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/) plugin? If not, can you please link to the site of the actual plugin you are using?

Comment: yes, you're correct, jquery simple slider plugin.

Comment: I've modified my answer to reflect the changes needed to make it work for the jQuery Simple Slider plugin. Hopefully this can help you get it functioning.

Comment: still no luck. I found an example that used this code to make a slider work similar to what I'm trying to achieve. I'm uncertain how to appropriate it though:                                                    `$(function(){
    osc = T("osc", wave="sin", freq=440, mul=1);
    osc.play();

    // Slider
    $("#freqslider").slider({
      value: 440,
      min: 50,
      max: 1200,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        freq = ui.value
        $("#freq").val(freq + "Hz");
        osc.freq.value = freq;
      }
    });
    $("#freq").val($("#freqslider").slider("value"));
  });`

Comment: heres a link to where i found the code: https://github.com/masui/timbretest/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery Simple Slider docs on [getting slider values](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/#getting-slider-values), the event you need to bind to is a custom event called `slider:changed`, not the standard DOM `change` event.

If you modify

```
$('#slider').on('change', function(){
    x = $(this).val();
});
```

to

```
$('#slider').on('slider:changed', function(evt, data){
    x = data.value;
});
```

you should be able to copy the new value of the slider to your global variable.

Comment: I made the change suggested above, but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: OK, a couple more details are needed then. Is this a jQuery UI slider, or another plugin? Can you also please include the code where you first create the slider.

Comment: <input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="1,000" id="slider">   The slider is called simple slider, but i could just easily use jquery ui, theres nothing special about this plugin